# Trying to dismiss a popover that was presented by storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

I see a lot of questions about this on SO but their answers do nothing to me.

I am presenting a popover using storyboard. After a while I want to dismiss that popover programmatically.

I have tried many things but the last try involves creating a class for the view controller that is inside the popover. The class is like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if (self) {
    [self initializeNotification];
  }
  return self;
}


- (void) initializeNotification {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserverForName:@"closePopover"
   object:self
   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
   usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }];
}
```

then, from the main code I post a notification like

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    postNotificationName:@"closePopover"
                  object:self];
```

and nothing happens... the popover continues there.

why?

Comment: Share full code, if you can

Comment: this is the full code. I click on a button, the button displays a ViewController from this class. I try to dismiss that later. It does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `self` with `nil` (for the `object` parameter) when creating the notification observer since it is not `self` that posts the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"closePopover" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: BRILLIANT? I thought this object was the object to where the notification was being assigned! THANKS! Works perfectly now!!!

Comment: Glad I could help :)